# Server Error in '/' Application when deploying a publish files on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I have a website created in C# when I execute that using visual studio it works fine but when I publish it and deploy it to the server it's giving me this error(see the screenshot)

[image]

Seems like from some where it's trying to refer to my local file system but not sure why and how can I fix this.
[image]

Comment: How does the `GetProjectDetails` look like? Seems like you are trying to load Json from file..

Comment: The references to your local file system is just metadata from the debug database file (pdb).  The issue is something related to reading an json array within your GetProjectDetails function.  Are you missing some static assets in your publishing package that exist locally that this function depends upon?

Comment: I am sure that I am not missing any static assets in my publishing package.

Comment: the same is working fine in my local so I assume that there is no JSON Array issue